# Getting an invoice number to be generated in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to generate an invoice number, but I'm getting `A non-numeric value encountered`. 
I think I'm missing something but I'm not sure what it is.

Here is the invoiceNumber() code in my helpers.php

```
function invoiceNumber()
{
    $orders = App\Order::all();

    if($orders->isEmpty())
    {
        $invoice = 'arm0001';
        return $invoice;
    }

    foreach($orders as $order)
    {
        $latest = App\Order::latest()->first();

        if($latest->invoice_number == true)
        {
            $invoice = 'arm'.$latest->invoice_number+1;
            return $invoice;
        }
    }
}
```

and this is where I'm trying to get it to be taken

```
public function deliveryConfirmation()
{
    $menus_child = Menu::where('menu_id', 0)->with('menusP')->get();
    $contacts = Contact::all();

    if(!Session::has('cart'))
    {
        return view('public.shopping-cart', compact('menus_child', 'contacts'));
    }

    $oldCart = Session::get('cart');
    $cart = new Cart($oldCart);

    $invoice_number = invoiceNumber();
    dd($invoice_number);

    return view('public.delivery-confirmation', ['products' => $cart->items, 'totalPrice' => $cart->totalPrice, 'menus_child' => $menus_child, 'contacts' => $contacts, 'invoice_number' => $invoice_number]);
}
```

I would really like to keep the 'ARM' in the database as well

Comment: What is the type of `invoice_number` in your database?

Comment: I think your database type for a column is an integer and you are trying to store a string.

Comment: My `invoice_number` is a string

Comment: That is why it is not able to add 1 in string in this line $invoice = 'arm'.$latest->invoice_number+1;

Comment: Try this, $invoice = 'arm' . ((int)$latest->invoice_number + 1);

Comment: It doesn't go any further then 1. So in the database I keep getting `arm1`

Comment: You can do like this to increment the number `$invoice = 'arm'.++$latest->invoice_number;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after seeing everyone's answer and from my understanding, it looked like everyone was separating the integer from the string to get it to work and it got me thinking about doing a `preg_replace()`. so I've adjusted my code to look like this

```
function invoiceNumber()
{
    $latest = App\Order::latest()->first();

    if (! $latest) {
        return 'arm0001';
    }

    $string = preg_replace("/[^0-9\.]/", '', $latest->invoice_number);

    return 'arm' . sprintf('%04d', $string+1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$invoice = 'arm' . ((int)$latest->invoice_number + 1);
```

...and with leading zeros (ARM0001):

```
$invoice = 'arm' . (str_pad((int)$latest->invoice_number + 1, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT));
```

Comment: Made an update to my code suggestion. Could you try that again?

Comment: ...and another one. With leading zeros, so you will get ARM0001.

Comment: It doesn't go any further then 1. So in the database I keep getting `arm1`

Comment: And the second one?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because the [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) of `.` and `+` is the same and so they are therefore evaluated left to right.

So if you break it down you get:

```
(('arm'.$latest->invoice_number)+1) -> ('arm123'+1)
```

where `arm123` would be a non-numeric value.

In this case you need to force the evaluation order by using parentheses:

```
 'arm'.($latest->invoice_number+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can increment you number by simply incremental `++` and keep your invoice number prefix.
like,

```
$invoice = 'arm'.++$latest->invoice_number;
```

`++$latest->invoice_number` this will increment your number by 1.
Hope it help you to achieve what you want.